# Compile error with Gearman and MySQL with Homebrew

Tags: mysql, homebrew, gearman

When attempting to compile Gearman on Mac OSX with Homebrew, I get the following error:

```
brew install gearman --with-mysql

libtool: compile:  clang++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -fvisibility=hidden -I/usr/include -D_THREAD_SAFE -DBUILDING_LIBGEARMAN -DHAVE_HTONLL -std=c++0x -g -O2 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Qunused-arguments -Wall -Wextra -Wno-attributes -Wvarargs -Waddress -Warray-bounds -Wchar-subscripts -Wcomment -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Wformat-y2k -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-overflow=1 -Wswitch-enum -Wundef -Wc++11-compat -Wunused -Wunused-result -Wunused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wformat-security -fwrapv -pipe -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wpacked -c libgearman-server/plugins/queue/mysql/queue.cc  -fno-common -DPIC -o libgearman-server/plugins/queue/mysql/.libs/libgearman_server_libgearman_server_la-queue.o
libgearman-server/plugins/queue/mysql/queue.cc:49:10: fatal error: 'mysql.h' file not found
#include <mysql.h>
         ^
1 error generated
```

I am using MariaDB instead of MySQL - and I suspect this may be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and easy workaround:

```
brew edit gearman
```

Look for this line:

```
args << (build.with?("mysql") ? "--with-mysql=#{Formula["mysql"].opt_bin}/mysql_config" : "--without-mysql")
```

And change `Formula["mysql"]` to `Formula["mariadb"]`

Run `brew install gearman --with-mysql` again and it will compile successfully.